# Migration scripts for nx nestjs typeorn

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, nomachine-nx, nestjs-typeorm

I am working with nx with typeorm and nestjs and I am Unable to generate migration
Here is my migration script

```
db.config.ts
export const  dataSourceOptions: DataSourceOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
  port: +process.env.DATABASE_PORT,
  username: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
  password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
  entities: [
    __dirname + '/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}',
  ],
  migrations: [
    __dirname + '/../migrations/*.migration{.ts,.js}',
  ],
  // cli: {
  //   migrationsDir: __dirname + '/../migrations',
  // },
  extra: {
    charset: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
  },
  migrationsTableName: 'migrations_typeorm',
  migrationsRun: Boolean(process.env.DATABASE_MIGRATION_SYNC),
  synchronize: Boolean(process.env.DATABASE_SYNC),
  // autoLoadEntities: true,
  ssl: ssl,
  logging: Boolean(process.env.DATABASE_LOGGING)
}

const dataSource = new DataSource(dataSourceOptions);
export default dataSource;





scripts:
"typeorm": {
      "executor": "nx:run-commands",
      "outputs": [],
      "options": {
        "command": "ts-node --project apps/project/tsconfig.json ./node_modules/typeorm/cli"
      }
    },
    "db-migration-gen": {
      "executor": "nx:run-commands",
      "outputs": [],
      "options": {
        "command": "nx run project:typeorm -- migration:generate apps/project/src/migration/{args.name} -d apps/project/src/config/db.config.ts"
      }
    },
```

Error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SY9FK.png)

I was trying to generate migration for my nx project with nestjs and typeorm but I was unable to generate migration getting the error which I have included as an image in descripton

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm late to the party, but I had the same problem and I recently figured out. I noticed that the tsconfig that I'm using doesn't have the `"module": "commonjs"` rule into the `compilerOptions` property. So instead i edited my command as the following:

`"command": "ts-node --project apps/project/tsconfig.app.json ./node_modules/typeorm/cli"`

My Nx installation automatically cretate that file for me on project generation. If not you should create one yourself and add the `module` rule to the `compilerOptions`.